# problems with aspx web resource

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd

**How do i get the WEBRESOURCE working under the situation where i have the CSS and the C# code within the same page.** . *The webresource in the CSS block says 'WebResource' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.*

I have already added `[assembly: WebResource("Common.AdResources.tick.png", "image/png")]` to the assembly and build action for the png file is set to embedded resource

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">

    .selling_points_title_row 
    {
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:14px;
        width: 250px;
    }

    .bui, .con { color: #636B3B; }
    .veh { color: #D4541D; }  

    .selling_points_header_row 
    {
        background-image: url('<%= WebResource("Common.AdResources.tick.png")%>');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:14px;
        width: 250px;
        padding-left: 30px;
    }

    .selling_points_content_row 
    {        
        font-family:trebuchet ms;
        font-size:12px;
        color: #333333;
        width: 250px;
        padding-left: 30px;
    }

    hr { color: #cccccc; }
</style>


    <script type="text/VB" runat="server">

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            Select Case Session("type")
                Case Is = "V"
                    vPoints.Visible = True
                Case Is = "B"
                    bPoints.Visible = True
                Case Is = "C"
                    cPoints.Visible = True
                Case Else
                    'Don't show anything
            End Select
        End Sub



    </script>
</head>
<body>

<asp:Panel id="vPoints" runat="server" visible="False">
<asp:Panel id="bPoints" runat="server" visible="False">
<asp:Panel id="cPoints" runat="server" visible="False">
```

Answer (score 1):

From within page code you need to call `ClientScriptManager.GetWebResourceUrl()`.

Check out MSDN for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getwebresourceurl

Comment: Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(Me.GetType(), "Common.AdResources.tick.png")

Tried that but in the runtime it throws an exception saying resource not found

Comment: The resource is unlikely to be embedded in the Page's own type, because the Page's type will be in a dynamically compiled assembly. You'll need to pass in a type that is in the assembly that contains the web resource. To double check this, you can print out Me.GetType().Assembly.CodeBase and then point .NET Reflector (or ILSpy) at the DLL and see if that resource is really there, with that name.

Comment: i checked into the assembly and it turns out that there is no resource with the name "tick". why would that happen and where could this resource be?

Comment: Where did you put the resource? Is it in the Visual Studio VBPROJ file as an embedded resource? If so, it will be in the application code DLL instead of the ASP.NET code DLL. Application code is the VB and RESX files in the project. The ASP.NET code is the ASPX/VBHTML files in the app. For the type to pass in, use one of the other types that are defined in one of the VB files in the project.